# Wordpress hosted in a subdirectory (of a rails app) has the wp-admin url without the subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

The blog is available at `http://www.example.com/blog`. The login url is accessible at `http://www.example.com/blog/wp-login.php`. But once logged in, the browser briefly shows `http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/` in the url field and then redirects and finally shows the dashboard at the url `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/`.

#### The Problem

Now all the url in the wordpress dashboard (eg: posts, pages, settings etc) are of the form `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/xxx.php` instead of the desired `http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/xxx.php`. When I click any of these links, the request goes to the rails app which throws an error as it obviously doesn't know this `wp-admin` path.

I have set the following in the wordpress' `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com/blog');
```

The apache conf file of the rails app has this reverse proxy setting:

```
ProxyPass /blog http://www.example.com:8080
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://www.example.com:8080
```

(yes, the wordpress is made to listen in another port)

This is the `.htaccess` file I have in the wordpress root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### The Confusion

I have very little knowledge of how htaccess works. But what's crazy is, this is based on another app(rails+wp) that's working with these exact same setup.

The only difference between the working and not-working apps(above) is that, the working site has no `www` in its root url as well as in its blog url. Could that be playing any hand here?

Any help is much appreciated as I'm struggling with it for weeks.

I'd be glad to furnish more details if you need them.

PS: There's no `.htaccess` file in the public folder of the rails app. The above mentioned htaccess file is present at the wordpress folder's root location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the database URL - WordPress stores the URL in the database in many places. Check https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ as an example of how to find/replace. Otherwise you can also go into the database and change it in the wp_options table, which might be enough for you to get in. Read up on how to change the URL: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL and try acting like you're changing from the wrong one to the right one, and it will likely fix the issue.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I changed the wp_options record with option_name as `siteurl`. Earlier it was 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress' as I had setup the site first locally and then deployed it to server. I now changed its value to 'http://www.example.com/blog'. Still the problem is not fixed. Same situation. (Since I had defined the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in the `wp-config.php` file, that took precedence and was reflected in the 'general settings' section of the wp site's admin section.)